# Analytic Proof Of ${n\choose r}={n-1\choose r-1}+{n-1\choose r}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Analytic Proof Of ${n\choose r}={n-1\choose r-1}+{n-1\choose r}$

---

**My Approach**

Let $x_k$ be one element in a set of $n$ elements.

1. $n-1\choose r-1$ $=$ the number of unique groups of $r$ containing $x_k$.
2. $n-1\choose r $ $=$ the number of unique groups of $r$ not containing $x_k$.

The number of unique groups of $r$ objects is equal to the number of groups containing a specific element plus the number of groups not containing that specific element.

---

**Will this suffice as an analytic proof?**

Comment: Your proof is fine, it's just that people will call it a **combinatorial** proof. An **analytical** proof to me would mean showing the RHS equals the LHS using the algebraic definition of $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: [See this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule#Combinatorial_proof)

Comment: @KimJongUn This question is from a chapter on combinatorics, so I wonder if that's okay in that context?

Comment: Your proof is correct. So to me, it doesn't really matter how you classify it. But if the question specifically tells you pursue an "analytic proof", I would use the algebraic approach mentioned above.

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi I suppose I could accept that as an answer if you post it as an answer?

Comment: Well it's not really a complete answer, more of a reference so doesn't matter much. As long as your question has been answered, I'm satisfied. :)

Comment: Okay I'll trust your judgement on the matter. Thank you for the input.

Comment: I think it is acceptable. However, people like more vigorous (more mathematical methods involved) proof like expanding the RHS, doing some factorizations, and recombining the temporary modified result back into one single combination (equals to the LHS). They will save the arguments like yours for the exercise in combinatorics. But, that is quite ‘taste’ independent.

Comment: $$
{\left(\,1 + z\,\right)^{\,\color{#c00000}{\Large n}} \over z^{\color{#c00000}{\Large r} + 1}}
={\left(\,1 + z\,\right)^{\,\color{#c00000}{\Large n - 1}} \over z^{\color{#c00000}{\Large r} + 1}}
+
{\left(\,1 + z\,\right)^{\,\color{#c00000}{\Large n - 1}} \over z^{\color{#c00000}{\Large r - 1} + 1}}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is very crude and not analytic enough. I hope you have been familiar with the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$. An analytic proof will be based exactly on those defintions and basic concepts of factorial.

The formula you want to prove is also known as Pascal triangle formula. The proof is followed:

Right Hand Side $$= \frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-r-1)!}$$
                $$= \frac{r(n-1)!+(n-r)(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
               $$= \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
               $$= \binom{n}{r}$$,
the first equality because of definition
,the second equality because of summing fractions
the third because of $n(n-1)!=n!$,
the fourth by definition.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this seems more appropriate, I agree. I Appreciate your input.

Comment: You are welcome. Just ask if you have any question. Good luck for your study.

Comment: I would call this an 'algebraic' proof. An 'analytic' proof would more likely be a proof using generating functions. Of course everything uses algebra to some extent, but the major category of a proof is the primary strategy.